# Is it possible to access the `request` and `response` objects in `functions.https.onCall` Firebase API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to access the `request` and `response` objects in `functions.https.onCall`.

My use case is that I would like to set cache headers on the response.

If there is no access to the headers, how are users of this API setting cache for both the CDN and browser?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use [`onRequest`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#onrequest) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `onCall` function you cannot access the `request`/`response` objects. You can verify exactly what the onCall function receives by checking [onCall types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_#oncall)

An alternative would be to use `functions.https.onRequest`, however this has security implications, functions published with onRequest are open, so you need to protect them in case you are accessing sensitive data, luckily there is a [boiler plate project](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/authorized-https-endpoint) that illustrates just that.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of the regular HTTPS request functions I was just hoping there was a way to access it using the `onCall` approach!

Comment: unfortunately no from my understanding of onCall. onCall is just an easier way to call functions directly from your apps so it comes with limitations I've been battling myself with onCall vs onRequest, the closer you'll get is [rawRequest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_https_.callablecontext#rawrequest) but that's just the request object.